# Angular CLI - ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I know that the command "ng serve" creates all my stuff in memory.

Now I have such url: http://localhost:4200/some-angular-route
But I want this url: http://localhost:4200/**subfolder**/some-angular-route

My Question is how can I create such a "subfolder"? My Problem is that in my production environment the requests go via Spring Boot Zuul and there are prefixes at urls.

Comment: Have you had a look at angular routing? https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set base href as follows

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/urlPrefix' }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also, when you build your code, you can give --directory and --baseHref as follows.

`ng build --deploy-url /mySubFolder/ --base-href /urlPrefix/`

You can find more here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: Had to use `--base-href` instead of `--bh`

Comment: @Maxence thanks for the comment. I've updated the question.